# Lower y points above maximum point

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cQLe.png)
I want the las three points to below the max that is 220

```
filtered_df = filtered_df.dropna(subset=['y'])
filtered_df['x'] = pd.to_numeric(filtered_df['x'], errors='coerce')
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(filtered_df['x], filtered_df['y'], marker='o', color='g')
plt.title('x v y')
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

how do I display a plot like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZxlM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). And [don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: You seem to have your y values as strings, not as numbers. Maybe `filtered_df['y'] = filtered_df['y'].astype(float)` would be sufficient.